# Can I stop a mobile app from shutting down

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

When a mobile app is closed it generates an event that can be captured.

```
// trap app shutdown event
Titanium.App.addEventListener(‘close’,function(e)
{
Ti.API.info(“The application is being shutdown”);
});
```

I would like to create an event handler that pops up an alert to ask "Are you sure you want to quit the app", just in case someone presses the wrong keys...

Is it this possible and can you cancel the shutdown event?

Comment: Not sure about Android but you can't on iOS.

Comment: My guess is that this is only an Andriod issue. Thanks Emilio.

Comment: But there is no such `shutting down` in android. Even the app is closed (not visible in the foreground) it is still possible that it continues to run because of some services.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it in Android only. It's not possible on iOS.**

Further, on Android, this can only be done if app is closed by pressing back button, not from task manager.

Here's how you do it on Android:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id='win'>

    </Window>
</Alloy>


// for Ti SDK 6.0.0.GA or above, you need to use this code
$.win.onBack = close;

// else use this code for SDK 5.5.1 or below
$.win.addEventListener('androidback', close);

function close() {
    alert('Do you want to shut down app????');
}
```

Read about the **[androidback event here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-androidback)**

And the ticket which added the above breaking change:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19919

Comment: Would it be possible to also add the app as an intent so users cant swipe/close? http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification

Comment: IMHO, it's probably not possible (at least using Titanium).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: **No, you cannot**

You can track events related to the lifecycle of the application but you cannot prevent that from happening. Without getting into the bad user experience that this could be let's talk about a user scenario will look like.

If you are using your Android phone and you want to close an app and it just keeps asking you if you are sure you want to close it, the programmer ignored the `Yes` action and keeps the app running. How insecure and annoying will this be?

Comment: I know it sounds insecure and annoying, but so too is inadvertently closing the app rather than backgrounding it. Specifically I am developing a GPS tracking app and one or two of my test users are complaining that they mistakenly close the app down rather than backgrounding. I want to try and prevent that before I go to market.

Comment: @Greg In that use case what I would suggest is to keep track of all the necessary information for you to "resume" the app task in case is accidentally closed. When the app opens you check that data, if you have something then you resume your action.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this problem by firstly hooking into the Android back event and secondly by using bencoding Alarm Manager to run the background code constantly. That way, if someone shut the UI down, the app continued to run in the background regardless.